# c# passing cookies as a parameter in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, cookies

I am trying to save cookies on a login page pass it to another page where it will be used as a parameter in sql.

saving cookies and redirecting to new page;

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserID");
cookie["UserID"] = reader["UserID"].ToString();
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
```

calling cookies

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["UserID"];
String strCookieValue = cookie.Value.ToString();
```

connection and assigning cookies to parameter

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial
Catalog=PMIS;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procGetUser", conn);
conn.Open();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strCookieValue;
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

UT = reader["UserType"].ToString();
```

here i get an error at UT saying Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `Read()` to move your reader into the first row.